# How to get the string just before specific character in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string

I have couple of strings like this:

- `Mar18L7`
- `Oct13H0L7`

I need to grab the string like:

- `Mar18`
- `Oct13H0`

Could any one please help on this using JavaScript? How can I split the string at the particular character?

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: `input.split("L")[0]`...?

Comment: Might not work in case of `April18L7`. Just in case there's a longer version of Month names somewhere.

Comment: Apart from L7 is there some other sample input you can provide so that we can generalise solution.

Comment: @ShubhamGupta thanks for suggestion we have some more like this Apr12R0  or  Jun12R0

Comment: @SiddAjmera thanks for your input, for april we denote like first three letters like this. Apr..

Comment: @EnigmaState, what about `Jul` ?

Comment: for july we are taking 'Jul' only

Comment: `L` from `Jul` would be in lower case in that case right?

Comment: yes in jul l is lowercase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `var str = 'Mar18L7';`

Try any of these:

1. `str.substr(0, str.indexOf('L7'));`
2. `str.split('L7')[0]`
3. `str.slice(0, str.indexOf('L7'))`
4. `str.replace('L7', '')`

Answer (score 1):

Based on input that is given it I have created following function which can take n string in array and return the output in the format you have given. Check if this helps and if some use case is missed.

```
function generateStr(arr, splitStr) {
  const processedStr = arr.map(value => value.split(splitStr)[0]);
  return processedStr.join(" OR ");
}

console.log(generateStr(["Mar18L7", "Oct13H0L7"], "L7"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex like this

```
var data = ["Mar18L7", "Oct13H0L7"];
var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\L[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
var output = []
data.forEach(function(el){
    var matches = el.match(regex);
    output.push(matches[1]);
});
```

output variable will be equal to  `['Mar18', 'Oct13H0']` and you can join all value usin the `.join` method on output array

```
var chain = output.join(" OR ");
// chain will be equal to "Mar18 OR Oct13H0"
```

Comment: You are welcome, can you choose one of all answer like response to your issue